# Understanding which database to use as the 'NAME' when connecting to an AWS RDS MySQL database using Django

Tags: python, django, database, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I created a new AWS mysql database instance with RDS, and I'm trying to connect to it from my Django app on my machine. Django requires the default database connection to be formatted like so in `settings.py`:

`DATABASES = {
  'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': 'innodb',
    'USER': 'username',
    'PASSWORD': 'password',
    'HOST': '--------.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com',
    'PORT': '####'
  }
}`

My question concerns the `'NAME'` parameter. I connected to the AWS instance from my command line using the provided endpoint and port number in the RDS console and checked to see what databases were there. This is a brand new database instance I created with RDS, and there were 5 databases.

`$ mysql -h ---------.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com -P #### -u username -p
Enter password:`

`mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| innodb             |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| sys                |
+--------------------+`

The only one of these databases that was empty was the one called `innodb`. At first I thought the `NAME` parameter was supposed to be 'mysql', since that is the name of the database server I'm using. But when I used 'mysql' as the name and ran `python manage.py migrate` I got an error saying

`django.db.migrations.exceptions.MigrationSchemaMissing: Unable to create the django_migrations table ((1044, "Access denied for user 'username' to database 'mysql'"))`

Changing the `NAME` to 'innodb' let me connect and write tables with the `migrate` command.

Why do I need to use the innodb database instead of mysql or any of the others? I didn't see any mention of 5 databases being created when I create a new RDS instance on AWS, and I could not find any mention of what name you are supposed to use when connecting to the RDS instance. What is the purpose of these 5 databases and why is innodb the only one that was empty and writable?

Comment: Those all look like system databases. When you created the database in RDS it asked for a DB name. It should show up as `DB Name` in the RDS console when you view the instance properties. If you didn't provide a DB name you might need to create a new database on the server before using it.

Comment: There is no field labeled DB Name on my console. How do you create a new database on the server?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-database.html

Answer (score 2):

It is in the Configuration tab.

[image]

Comment: what does that - in DB name mean? and what exactly is the DB name here??

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem, it's not very intuitive with AWS.

But if you open de RDS console and open the instance involved, you can see under Details/Configuration the DB name and user:

[image]

Comment: Strange, there is no field labeled DB Name on my console.

Answer (score 0):

You can install mysql client on your local system, and connect with RDS (using endpoint). That will give all DB names etc.

AWS also create few databases by itself, for postgres I am aware it creates as "rdsadmin" (for its internal purpose)

The DB name that you have created, shall appear on console under section of Details --> Configurations --> DB Name (it is below Created Time)

Answer (score 0):

In this case, OP was using MySQL, so it should always have a name.

Looking through the comments (for Ahmed Aziz's answer), some people were confused about the "-" character showing up under "Database Name". This is sometimes the case if you use "PostgreSQL", in which case you should use the default name of "postgres".

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_CreateDBInstance.html

> PostgreSQL:
> It must contain 1–63 alphanumeric characters.
> It must begin with a letter or an underscore. Subsequent characters can be letters, underscores, or digits (0-9).
> The initial database name is postgres.