# AWS lambda: RDS MySQL database not found

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

I have an AWS lambda code which tries to connect to an RDS database. It does not work but an error message is displayed:

```
Error: Unknown database 'perf-mgmt'
    at PromisePool.execute (/opt/node_modules/mysql2/promise.js:374:22)
    at Runtime.handler (file:///var/task/index.mjs:24:43) {
  code: 'ER_BAD_DB_ERROR',
  errno: 1049,
  sql: undefined,
  sqlState: '42000',
  sqlMessage: "Unknown database 'perf-mgmt'"
}
```

My lambda code follows:

```
import mysql from 'mysql2/promise';
import AWS from 'aws-sdk';

export const handler = async (event) => {
    try {
        // Database configuration using environment variables
        const dbConfig = {
            host: process.env.RDS_HOSTNAME,
            user: process.env.RDS_USERNAME,
            database: process.env.RDS_DATABASE,
            password: process.env.RDS_PASSWORD,
            port: 3306, // Default MySQL port
        };
        // Create a connection pool
        const pool = await mysql.createPool(dbConfig);
        // Use the pool to query the database
        
        const query = createGoalGroupTable();
        
        const [rows, fields] = await pool.execute(query);
        // Process the result as needed
        //const result = rows.map(row => );

        return {
            statusCode: 200,
            body: JSON.stringify('Hello from Lambda'),
        };
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    } 

};



function createGoalGroupTable () {
    const createTableQuery = `
            CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS GoalGroup (
                goalGroupId int,
                goalgroupName VARCHAR(100),
                companyName VARCHAR(100),
                display BOOLEAN,
                defaultItem BOOLEAN
            )
        `;
    return createTableQuery;
}
```

The RDS_DATATBASE is simply the name of the database as visible in the RDS console. If I use the database ARN, there is no difference, the same errormessage is displayed.
The pool.execute line is faulty and results in the error.
My database is publicly accessible.

What shall I do to fix the issue?
Thanks.

Comment: The error message suggests that you are connecting to the database server, and it is only complaining about the name of the database. Perhaps try a name of `innodb`? See: [Understanding which database to use as the 'NAME' when connecting to an AWS RDS MySQL database using Django](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51971385/174777)